# Remove irrelevant logs on BackgroundPreinitializer

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, logging, tomcat8.5

**EDIT**  I can't upgrade tomcat now so the related answer isn't relevant here

We are using 8.5.50 and encounter [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67857751/spring-migration-4-3-to-5-on-tomcat-8-5-el-api-error) which produce logs as:

```
2021-06-06 12:37:50,482 DEBUG [background-preinit] messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator (ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:220) - Failed to load expression factory via classloader ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ROOT
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@76f856a8

javax.el.ELException: Unable to find ExpressionFactory of type [# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more]
        at javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:154) ~[el-api.jar:3.0.FR]
        at javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:93) ~[el-api.jar:3.0.FR]
        at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.canLoadExpressionFactory(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:216) [hibernate-validator-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.buildExpressionFactory(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:170) [hibernate-validator-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.<init>(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:94) [hibernate-validator-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.AbstractConfigurationImpl.getDefaultMessageInterpolator(AbstractConfigurationImpl.java:573) [hibernate-validator-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.AbstractConfigurationImpl.getDefaultMessageInterpolatorConfiguredWithClassLoader(AbstractConfigurationImpl.java:822) [hibernate-validator-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.AbstractConfigurationImpl.getMessageInterpolator(AbstractConfigurationImpl.java:483) [hibernate-validator-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl.<init>(ValidatorFactoryImpl.java:153) [hibernate-validator-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.buildValidatorFactory(HibernateValidator.java:38) [hibernate-validator-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.AbstractConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(AbstractConfigurationImpl.java:451) [hibernate-validator-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.BackgroundPreinitializer$ValidationInitializer.run(BackgroundPreinitializer.java:149) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.BackgroundPreinitializer$1.runSafely(BackgroundPreinitializer.java:111) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.BackgroundPreinitializer$1.run(BackgroundPreinitializer.java:102) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: # Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1358) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.50]
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1180) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.50]
        at javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:147) ~[el-api.jar:3.0.FR]
        ... 14 more
```

I failed to remove the logs using application's log4j and also using tomcat/conf/logging.properties

> ```
> messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.level = INFO
> org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.level = INFO
> ```

How can such logs be removed?

Relevant dependencies:

```
    <apache.commons.logging-version>1.1.3</apache.commons.logging-version>
    <apache.httpcomponents-version>4.5.2</apache.httpcomponents-version>
    <apache.log4j-new-version>2.0.2</apache.log4j-new-version>
    <apache.log4j-old-version>1.2.17</apache.log4j-old-version>
    
    <org.slf4j-version>1.7.21</org.slf4j-version>
    <hibernate-version>5.5.0.Final</hibernate-version>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.log4j-new-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.log4j-old-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.log4j-old-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.commons.logging-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring migration 4.3 to 5 on tomcat 8.5 el-api error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67857751/spring-migration-4-3-to-5-on-tomcat-8-5-el-api-error)

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz no, I can't upgrade tomcat now, I want to stop seeing the errors in log

Comment: you should upgrade, since the version you are using has [multiple vulnerabilities](https://tomcat.apache.org/security-8.html).

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz yes, but we upgrading other components and tomcat won't be upgraded soon

Comment: Can you provide your dependencies? Hibernate uses [JBoss logging](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/topical/html/logging/Logging.html), which chooses the logging framework according to the classpath (like JCL). BTW: the properties in your question lack the final `.level`.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Thank you, Not working also with `.level` and added my log related pom

Comment: Can you add your Log4j 2 configuration (`log4j2.xml` or equivalent)?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz adding logger in log4j2 helped, you can add an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate 4.x and higher uses JBoss Logging as logging interface (cf. [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/logging/Logging.html)).  In order to ignore those messages, you need to identify which logging system is generating them.

With your dependencies all Hibernate messages should go to Log4j 2. Setting:

```xml
<Logger name="org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation" level="INFO" />
```

should disable the messages.

**Remark:** Your Log4j 1.x logging system is misconfigured: you have both `log4j` and `log4j-over-slf4j` (a replacement for Log4j 1.x, which sends everything to SLF4j) among your dependencies. Which one of the two implementation will be chosen is random.