# Tomcat Docker Container Error Javax.Servlet

Tags: java, docker, tomcat, sap

We have an application Calatena based on Java, usually we use tomcat to run on local without problems.

We need to enable application on SAP and on a running Docker.

I tried with tomcat:8.0 and tomcat:9.0.

In both cases there is a `javax.servlet ServerRealm ClassNotFoundException`.

I pulled both tomcat versions as shown below to enable a container where I used the dockerfile to load the `calatena6.war` into the container.

## tomcat:8.0

```
docker image pull tomcat:8.0

docker container create --publish 8082:8080 --name my-tomcat-container tomcat:8.0

docker container start my-tomcat-container

docker container exec -it my-tomcat-container bash

PS C:\Users\Public\Documents\web-app\Calatena6> docker container exec -it my-tomcat-container9 bashner9 bash

root@15560e742bb9:/usr/local/tomcat# cd conf

root@15560e742bb9:/usr/local/tomcat/conf# rm catalina.properties

root@15560e742bb9:/usr/local/tomcat/conf# rm tomcat-users.xml
```

It is showing tomcat manager but displaying error message:
[image: Tomcat error]

## tomcat:9.0

```
PS C:\Users\Public\Documents\web-app\Calatena6> docker cp "C:\Java\apache-tomcat-9.0.43\lib" dcb5242ce4a6:/usr/local/tomcat/lib/ext

" " docker cp "C:\Java\apache-tomcat-9.0.43\conf\catalina.properties" dcb5242ce4a6:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/

" " docker cp "C:\Java\apache-tomcat-9.0.43\conf\catalina.properties" dcb5242ce4a6:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/

" " docker cp "C:\Java\apache-tomcat-9.0.43\bin\setenv.bat" dcb5242ce4a6:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/

" " docker cp "C:\Java\apache-tomcat-9.0.43\bin\setenv.sh" dcb5242ce4a6:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/

" " docker image build -t your_name/some-app-image ./
```

It is not working at all:
[image: tomcat9 errormessage]

Comment: [do not post errors as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), please

Comment: I have reorganized the question so that people can first read your explanation, then see what you exactly did. Please edit it if I changed the meaning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring migration 4.3 to 5 on tomcat 8.5 el-api error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67857751/spring-migration-4-3-to-5-on-tomcat-8-5-el-api-error)